# c# mvc: RedirectToAction() and browser navigation buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, redirect

In my application, i am storing an object into session which is passed to a web service to return data to display in a table. If the session exists, then it will not ask the user to input fresh data. However, if a user selects a link called "New List", then the session data will be cleared and the user prompted to enter new data.

In my code, i have an anchor defined like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("NewList", "Alert")"> New List</a>
```

Which will trigger this Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult NewList()
{
     Session["new_list"] = "y";
     return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

And then continue to execute this action:

```
 public ActionResult List()
    {
         if ((string)Session["new_list"] == "y")
         {
             //clear session variables, load fresh data from API
         }else{
             //display blank table. Ask user to input data to retrieve a list
         }
      ....
     }
```

Now, the issue i have is when a user navigates away from the list page, and then navigates back with the browser's back button, it is still calling `newlist`. In the history of the browser, instead of storing `List` it is storing `newlist` which is causing the session variable to clear. What can i do to stop this from happening or is there a different mechanism to use in c# mvc that can help me achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Put it in a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem here is that the NewList action uses **GET** when it should really be a **POST**.

A **GET** request is never supposed to alter the state of a resource, but simply return the current state of the resource; while a **POST** request allows for the altering of a resource.

Because you allow the NewList action to be called with a GET request, the user's browser assumes (quite rightly on its part) that nothing bad/undesired will happen if it simply repeats the request in the future, e.g. when a user uses the back button.

If instead a POST request is issued, a user browser will never re-issue the request without the user confirming they actually intended to re-issue it.

The solution to your problem then is modify this to the standard **PRG** pattern: **POST/Redirect/GET**; that is, send a POST request to perform the state change, redirect the user browser to another page, and GET the result page. In this scheme, pressing the back-button would effectively "skip" over the state change action and go the previous page the user was on.

To accomplish this in MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewList()
{
    //clear session variables, load fresh data from API
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}

public ActionResult List()
{
    // whatever needs to happen to display the state
}
```

This does mean that you can't provide the "New List" action directly as a hyperlink in the page, as these will always issue GET requests. You will need to use a minimal form like so: `<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("NewList", "Alert")"><button type="submit">New List</button></form>`. You can style the button to look like a normal hyperlink as desired.

Comment: this is a good solution. thanks for taking the time to answer. Although i think i may have found a shorter solution, which is to use `[HttpGet, OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]` above the action definition. This will force the browser to load a page from scratch rather than from its cache. Which is what appears to be happening right now

Comment: I don't believe your issue has anything at all to do with caching, especially since you note that a user pressing the back button will inadvertently clear their list (which indicates the browser sent a request to the server and didn't serve it up from its cache!)
There are security considerations for this as well, consider that under your current scheme, I can place an <img> or <script> tag on another website with the URL for NewList and blank out the list of any user of your website whenever they visit that site.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it storing NewList is because you are redirecting to "Alert/NewList", and its the string in your URL for making hit to "NewList" Action, So whenever you are try back button the browser gets this "Alert/NewList" URL, hence its making hit to action "NewList".
But now, I am not getting why the session gets clear. because you are initializing the session in "NewList" itself. Still i suggest you to use local-storage to assign values with session.